# Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine, failing due to project having signing certificate

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have about 100 applications to republish, am I using microsoft.build to accomplish this task.  Well about 40 of them will not republish because they have `Error  1   Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store.`

I know I could go through all one by one and remove that property from the project, but that would take a long... time.

This is the code I'm using below, I'm wondering is there a way to turn that property off via code?

```
 Console.WriteLine("building: " + f.FullName);
            Engine engine = new Engine();
            engine.GlobalProperties.SetProperty("Configuration", "Release");

            bool success = engine.BuildProjectFile(f.FullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you building your MSBuild project files from the code above?

If you know what property you need to remove in each project then you can set the value in  your code or via the MSBuild command line.

If you remove all of these properties or set them to null then you will not get this error.

```
<manifestcertificatethumbprint> </manifestcertificatethumbprint>
<manifestkeyfile></manifestkeyfile>
<generatemanifests></generatemanifests>
<signmanifests></signmanifests>
```

You could also pass in these parameter values from the MSBuild command line.

However, if you need to sign your Assemblies then you will need to provide a new Key.snk file in order to sign your assemblies.

`MSBUILD solutiontoBuild.sln /p:SignAssembly=false;DelaySign=false`